# I am creating a function that returns a tuple showing a boolean

Tags: python

I have to create a program that shows True or False if the elements from a list are palindromes or not.

I already has created the first part

```
    def es_palindromo(texto):
    rta = ""
    for i in range(len(texto)):
        rta += texto[i]
    if (rta == texto):
        print(True)
    elif (rta != texto):
        print(False)
    return rta
es_palindromo("bob")
```

Now, I am trying to create a new function that shows me the amount of palindromes words and the ones that are not. Should be on a tuple and give something like this `:(1, 2[True, False, True])` and the list would be

```
list = ["oso","hola","bob"]
```

Comment: `2[True, False, True]` is not valid python.

Comment: Your code has severe indentation issue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your texto is coming in form of a list, you can access the items outrightly. Try this

```
def es_palindromo(texto):
    ans= [True if x ==x[::-1] else False for x in texto]
    count = [ans.count(i) for i in set(ans) ]
    print(count)
    return (count,ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all in your code there is an indentation problem, also the output you are expecting is not valid in python. However, the below code will return a tuple with first element as number of palindrome strings and second element as a list stating if the given strings in the input list are palindrome or not.

```
list1 = ["oso","hola","bob"] #list variable
def es_palindromo(texto):
    if texto == texto[::-1]:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def return_tuple(input_list):
    count = 0
    ans = []
    for i in list1:
        if es_palindromo(i):
            count+=1
            ans.append(return_tuple(i))
    return (count,ans)

return_tuple(list1)
```